# Cycles of length 6 in $K_{m,n}$

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

We want to find the number of cycles of length $6$ in the complete bipartite graph $K_{m,n}$.

My idea was, that for such a cycle, since the graph is bipartite, we need $3$ vertices from each of the components. The number of such choices is $$\binom{n}{3} \binom{m}{3}$$

But in the problem's solution, our professor states that for each of these choices of vertices we get $6$ different cycles. I tried direct counting but I think I'm getting lost somewhere along the way and I only count $4$ different cycles. Any help on how to count these?

Comment: @Arthur no the excercise doesn't mention anything about directed cycles

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose the vertices are $(v_i)$, $(w_i)$ for $1\leq i\leq 3$.

The number of orderings of these $6$ vertices that begins with a $v_i$ is $3!\times 3! = 36$ (the odd positions must all have $v_i$s and the even positions $w_i$s).
For any cycle, there are $3\times 2 = 6$ possible representations as such an ordering ($3$ for which $v_i$ you begin from and $2$ for which direction you go along the cycle in).

So, the number of cycles that can be formed from these $6$ vertices is $(3!)^2/6 = 6$.